# Server monitoring tool for Nginx+Apache+wsgi+django

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, nginx, monitoring

I'm running website on Ubuntu server with following chains:
Web server - Nginx+Apache(worker)+mod_wsgi+django
Background workers - celery, rabbitmq
DBs - mysql, mongo

I'm looking for a best ( and simple to deploy ) server monitoring tool with web interface. I've checked several of them - zabbix, monit and some other. It seems all of them are on PHP and thus require Apache to be in prefork mode. 
I found no installation tips for nginx, so my questions are:
1) Which tool may be preferred for monitoring most of my env
2) Please point on most simple tool to deploy on nginx or apache-worker

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Monit doesn't require Apache and it's incredibly simple to install. It's designed to meet all of your requirements.

HTH!

Tom Purl

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Munin?  It runs with a client/server model, with a process running on each server to be monitored and the central "reporting" server connecting to each in order to gather stats on your services.

It creates charts without using PHP, and runs every few minutes. There are a lot of plugins available for it as well.  I don't know offhand if they offer plugins for every service you run (I use the mongodb plugins, and they're quite nice), but if you know a little programming (bash, perl, python, whatever), they are extremely easy to write.  Installation is easy, and packages are available for a lot of systems.